# Extract HTML Table from Web Page source in Unity

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, unity-game-engine

I build a script in C# for Unity to read & download a specific webpage source in a text file in Unity, what I really want to achieve is to extract from this pages only html tables data, for example I want to remove all the lines from **DOCTYPE html PUBLIC** to **table class="formular"** to extract table & data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://mywebsite.com/favicon.ico" />
<title>My Website Com</title>
<meta name="description" content="Ministerul pentru intreprinderi mici si mijlocii, comert, turism si profesii liberale"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="My Web Site/>
<meta name="Language" content="en"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="rating" content="General" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="7 Days" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="publisher" content="Unity Design" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (c) Unity Design" />
<meta name="author" content="Developed by Unity Design - www.UnityDesign.com" />
<link href="/css/style.css?t=2017061401" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/uploader.css?t=2017061401" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script>
    var jQr = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mootools-1.2.5-core-yc.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mootools-1.2.5.1-more.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploader/Swiff.Uploader.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploader/Fx.ProgressBar.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploader/Lang.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploader/FancyUpload2.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.js?t=2017061401"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>
</head>
<body onload="$('ajaxloader').setStyle('display','none')"><div id="container">

 <div class="logo_container">
  <a href="/" id="logo" title="MWC - Home Page"><img src="/i/logo.png?40084" /></a>
  
  <div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:107px;" id="ajaxloader"><img src="/i/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="menu_top">
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/" title="Home Page"><h2>Home Page</h2></a>
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/contact/" title="Contact"><h2>Contact</h2></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <div style="padding:5px 0;"></div>

<div id="content" ><h1>List of items: Example</h1><br><br>

 <div class="tableExample" style="padding-left:0;">
 <table class="formular">
  <tr>
   <th>Position</th>
   <th>Name of item</th>
   <th>Date added</th> 
     </tr>
       <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>2017-07-14 19:19</td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>2017-07-14 19:30</td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Kelly</td>
    <td>2017-07-14 18:44</td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>2017-07-12 12:49</td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>William</td>
    <td>2017-07-13 00:26</td>
       </tr>
   </table> 
 </div>
```

Any ideas how can achieve this?

Comment: How do you have the HTML stored? Can you iterate through it line by line, and does it always have the same format (each tag on its own line, not minified etc.)?

Comment: Hi @Minzkraut, every HTML Page I store temporary in a text file, and yes the page structure is the same every time, with the same amount of lines. Thanks!